# Converging sequence $a_{{n+1}}=6\, \left( a_{{n}}+1 \right) ^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

I know the sequence is converging. But I find it difficult proving it, by induction. So far I have drawn a diagram and calculate the five first numbers. From the diagram I can se that the sequence can be split into two sequences, one that is increasing and one tha is decreasing. I need to show that

> I need to show that
>   $a_{{1}}=1$,
>   $a_{{3}}=3/2$ and
>   $a_{{5}}={\frac {30}{17}}$ is an increasing sequence and that
>   $a_{{2}}=3$, 
>   $a_{{4}}={\frac {12}{5}}$ is decreasing.

Any help would be appriciated.

$a_{{1}}=1, a_{{n+1}}=6\, \left( a_{{n}}+1 \right) ^{-1},1\leq n$

- $a_{{1}}=1$
- $a_{{2}}=3$
- $a_{{3}}=3/2$
- $a_{{4}}={\frac {12}{5}}$
- $a_{{5}}={\frac {30}{17}}$

Comment: To help with intuition, what would it mean if it *does* converge to a specific limit, say, $\alpha$.  Then as $n$ grows large, we would have $a_n\approx a_{n+1}\approx \alpha$, implying that $\alpha = 6(\alpha+1)^{-1}$.  Can you use that to solve for what $\alpha$ would have to be?

Comment: I need to show that a1, a2, a3... is an increasing sequence and that the a2,a4, a5 is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Hint: make an assumption about the sequence first, then use induction.

Answer (score 2):

(At the end,
I have added my form
of the explicit solution.)

$a_{1}=1, a_{n+1}=\dfrac{6}{a_{{n}}+1},1\leq n
$

If it has a limit $L$,
then
$L = \dfrac{6}{L+1}$
or
$L^2+L-6 = 0
$
or
$(L+3)(L-2) = 0
$.

Since
$a_n > 0$
for all $n$,
the only possibility
is $L=2$.

To get a sequence
whose terms should
go to $0$,
let
$a_n = b_n+2
$.
Then
$b_{n+1}+2=\dfrac{6}{b_{{n}}+3}
$
or
$b_{n+1}
=\dfrac{6-2(b_{n}+3)}{b_{n}+3}
=\dfrac{-2b_{n}}{b_{n}+3}
$.

Since
$b_1 = a_1-2
= -1
$,
$b_2 = \dfrac{2}{2}
= 1
$,
$b_3 = \dfrac{-2}{4}
= \dfrac12
$,
$b_4 = \dfrac{-1}{7/2}
= -\dfrac{2}{7}
$.

Since
$\left(-\dfrac{2 x}{x+3}\right)' = -\dfrac{6}{(x+3)^2}
$,

if
$-\dfrac12 \le b_n
\le \dfrac12$,
then
$b_{n+1}
\le \dfrac{1}{5/2}
=\dfrac25
\lt \dfrac12
$
and
$b_{n+1}
\ge \dfrac{-1}{7/2}
=-\dfrac27
\gt -\dfrac12
$.

Therefore
$|b_n|
\le \dfrac12
$
for $n \ge 3$.

Therefore,
for
$n \ge 3$,

$\begin{array}\\
\left|\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right|
&=\left|\dfrac{2}{b_n+3}\right|\\
&\le \dfrac{2}{5/2}\\
&= \dfrac45\\
&< 1\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$b_n
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.

Therefore
$a_n
\to 2
$
as $n \to \infty$.

(added later)

I can show that
$b_m
= \frac{15}{8(-\frac32)^m-3}
$
so that
$b_{2m}
=\frac{15}{8(\frac94)^{m}-3}
$
is decreasing
and
$b_{2m+1}
=\frac{-5}{4(\frac94)^{m}+1}
$
is increasing,
both approaching $0$
as their limit.

Comment: +1 for the beautiful solution. I have taken liberty to change "frac" into "dfrac" so that the fractions look bigger in size.

Comment: I have added my form of the explicit solution.

Comment: My more general question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720787/find-the-solution-to-and-limit-of-a-n1-fracva-nw-with-a-10-v-0

Answer (score 0):

You can actually outright solve this sequence and take the limit. You can prove this by induction.

$$a_n = \frac{15 (-2)^n}{8 \times 3^n - 3(-2)^n} + 2$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ gives you 2.

Comment: I do not see the solution

Comment: "solving the sequence" means getting an explicit formula for all $a_n$ independent of previous values and that is what is shown. Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ gives the value which the sequence converges to

Comment: I mean even if you don't use wolfram alpha, whatever you do in your head is not much of mathematical value than actually using wolfram alpha.

Comment: Tho whom do you adress that comment??

Comment: @aboat: I strongly disagree. If you use Wolfy, you had better know *what* you are doing and *why* you are doing it. I sometimes use it to do moderately involved calculations or when I am lazy, but I could always to these by hand, and I always know why I am doing the calculation.

Comment: It's impressive that Wolfy gives the solution to the recurrence as a(n) = -(6 (c_1+(-2/3)^n))/((-1/3)^n 2^(n+1)-3 c_1), which goes to 2 for all positive $a_1$.